# Как создать список не перезаписывая его?

Tags: bash, list

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой записи данных в список. Попробую пояснить кодом.
В начале функции я создаю список

```
list=()
```

Дальше пишу функцию

```
if [ "$var1" -eq 1 ]
then list="Privet"
elif [ "$var" -eq 1 ]
then list="poka"
fi
echo $list
```

В таком случае я на выводе я получаю лишь последнюю `privet`, а хочется в списке видеть и `privet` и `poka`.
Возможно `elif`в данном случае неуместен, поэтому и прошу помощи.
Заранее всем спасибо!
P.S. `var1` и `var2`при этом имеют значение 1

Comment: Если вы хотите добавить в список элементы, то можно использовать `list+=(Privet)`

Answer (score 1):

добавить строку `e` как отдельный элемент в массив `a`:

```
a+=(e)
```

вывести в *stdout* содержимое массива `a`:

```
echo ${a[@]}
```